# Can I/How to bind jQuery events to form element load when loading Rails partials?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to call a function whenever a form element (hidden field, specifically) with a certain class loads. This:

```
$('.has_other').ready(function(){
    alert($(this).value);
});
```

works fine on the initial page load, but when I reload the form partial that contains the element with the "has_other" class (for editing an element using the same form), the event does not get called again. Is there a way in jQuery to cause this function to be called on all loads of the hidden field, including reloads/loads of partials within the existing page?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I render the partial like this in my controller:

```
page.replace_html 'secondary_publication_entry', :partial => 'publications/form'
```

**Edit 2:** Here is more specific code:

```
$j('.has_other_hidden').live('ready', function(){
    alert($j(this).value);
});
```

Have also tried

```
$j('.has_other_hidden').ready(function(){
    alert($j(this).value);
});
```

and

```
$j('.has_other_hidden :hidden').live('ready', function(){
    alert($j(this).value);
});
```

The only one of these that causes any alerts is .ready(), which does **not** cause the alerts on partial load/reload, which is what I would like to happen.

I guess I could call a function that calls ready() again when I reload each partial - I'm not sure how to do this though (call a jquery function from a rails controller).

Thanks for the answers!

**Edit 3:** I've tried live('load',...) and live('ready',...). Neither work here :(

Comment: I'm not sure but did you try to place your code inside partial? It should be invoked every time new partial loads

Comment: I'm not sure how to call a jQuery function from a rails controller where I load the partial... help?

Comment: no not from the controller just plase your js code inside partial Well I've never used prototype but in case of jquery.get you may place your js code inside action.js.erb so maybe if you place your code inside partial and render partial from controller the code'll be executed and new objects(which were added with partial) also will be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of gross, but if `live()` isn't working, you could undo and redo all the bindings manually. Example:

```
function bindMyStuff() {
  $('a').unbind('click');
  $('a').click(funciton() {
    alert("I've been clicked!");
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  bindMyStuff();
});
```

Then your partial could call `bindMyStuff()` within script tags.

Comment: oh man. First I get a 'handler is undefined' error when I just define a bindMyStuff() function. And unfortunately the bindMyStuff function doesn't do anything when I try to add in unbind and .load() instead of .click(). Calling an external function from my partial is probably the direction I need to go in though, thank you for that idea!

Comment: ok, I was thinking that I could use live() with .load(), so that when another element of the original class loaded (such as in a partial) the function would be called.

Comment: @Sarah: did you try to unbind and rebind .ready() instead of .load()?

Comment: .ready() did it! So I guess my answer was a) call function from partial on load  and b) unbind and rebind .ready(). A little messy but I'll see if it can get me where I'm going. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @Sarah: one more thought... if live() doesn't work with ready(), it probably should. Consider checking to see if this is a known bug in jQuery, and if not, submit a ticket, using the most simplified version of your example you can provide. Contribute to open source!

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the live method of jQuery library. I think this will work

```
$('.has_other').live('load', function(){
    alert($(this).value);
});
```

If that doesn't work try firing the event after the ajax request that reloads that partial.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already tried live(). Unfortunately nothing happens with that, even when the main form loads initially.

Comment: live is the solution you are looking for, could you post the code you are looking for with .live? Also, have you completely removed prototype/added jQuery noConflict?

Comment: See my update - I've had no luck with live() in this situation. I don't think live works with 'ready'/'load'?

Answer (score 0):

Is this field hidden? If it is $('.has_other') will only return fields that are visible.

$('.has_other :hidden')

should get the hidden element.